# Why these seemed right hadoop streaming python scripts do not work?

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I have a set of hadoop streaming job, like below:

bash file:

```
hadoop fs -rmr /tmp/someone/sentiment/

hadoop jar /opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.0.0-0.cdh5b2.p0.27/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-2.jar \ 
           -input /user/hive/warehouse/tweetjsonsentilife20 \
           -output /tmp/someone/sentiment/ \
           -mapper "mapper_senti.py" \
           -reducer "reducer_senti5.py" \
           -file mapper_senti.py \
           -file reducer_senti5.py \
           -cmdenv dir1=http://ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/home/ubuntu/aclImdb/train/pos \
           -cmdenv dir2=http://ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal:8088/home/ubuntu/aclImdb/train/pos/ \
```

mapper:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
     keyval=line.strip().split("\t")
     key,val=(keyval[0],keyval[0])
     if key!="\N" and val!="\N":
        sys.stdout.write('%s\t%s\n' % (key, val))
```

reducer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import os





for line in sys.stdin:
     keyval=line.strip().split("\t")
     key,val=(keyval[0],keyval[1])
     limit=1
     dir1=os.environ['dir1']
     dir2=os.environ['dir2']
     for file in os.listdir(dir1)[:limit]:
       for word in set(open(dir2+file).read()):
          value=word
          print "%s\t%s" % (key,value)
```

and the error:

```
rmr: DEPRECATED: Please use 'rm -r' instead.
14/06/18 22:10:57 INFO fs.TrashPolicyDefault: Namenode trash configuration: Deletion     interval = 1440 minutes, Emptier interval = 0 minutes.
Moved: 'hdfs://ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/tmp/natashac/sentiment' to     trash at: hdfs://ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal:8020/user/ubuntu/.Trash    /Current
14/06/18 22:10:59 WARN streaming.StreamJob: -file option is deprecated, please use     generic option -files instead.
packageJobJar: [mapper_senti.py, reducer_senti5.py] [/opt/cloudera/parcels    /CDH-5.0.0-0.cdh5b2.p0.27/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/hadoop-streaming-2.2.0-cdh5.0.0-beta-2.jar]     /tmp/streamjob8672448578858048676.jar tmpDir=null
14/06/18 22:11:00 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at   ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.0.77:8032
14/06/18 22:11:01 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at     ip-10-0-0-77.us-west-2.compute.internal/10.0.0.77:8032
14/06/18 22:11:01 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/06/18 22:11:01 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/06/18 22:11:02 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job:     job_1402902347983_0058
14/06/18 22:11:02 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1402902347983_0058
14/06/18 22:11:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://ip-10-0-0-77.us-    west-2.compute.internal:8088/proxy/application_1402902347983_0058/
14/06/18 22:11:02 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1402902347983_0058
14/06/18 22:11:09 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1402902347983_0058 running in uber mode : false
14/06/18 22:11:09 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/06/18 22:11:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/06/18 22:11:22 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1402902347983_0058_r_000001_0,     Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
        at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeReducer.close(PipeReducer.java:134)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.IOUtils.cleanup(IOUtils.java:237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:459)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:392)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:165)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
```

Seems the syntax everything is right. But did not work. Seems mapper is ok. But not reducer. Anyone has any idea about this?

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your jobtracker log?

Answer (score 0):

Where do you think dir1 and dir2 would be? The reducer runs on some node assigned by YARN and it probably can't locate these

Comment: Thank you for your reply. My dir1, dir2 are physically on the master node. We have a distributed system. One master QA node, and 4 slave QA nodes. The dir1 and dir2 are on the master node. We use AWS. we just changed the nodes to some old nodes, and retired the old nodes. I vaguely remember the hadoop streaming job worked on the old nodes. Not sure. Thank you!

Comment: YARN will assign a random node (depending on load) to handle the reduce - i.e. most likely not on the node where dir1 and dir2 are defined

Comment: Thank you Arnon. I am just confused. If the YARN can not locate these. How could other people's -cmdenv in hadoop streaming bash file, and os.environ in python work? Thank you. Why ppl made this -cmdenv and os.environ? It is not useful I feel if it is the case.

Comment: I think you are right, Arnon. I put the files one each of the node. And wrote the code to be:-cmdenv dir1=/home/ubuntu/aclImdb/train/pos \
           -cmdenv dir2=/home/ubuntu/aclImdb/train/pos/ \. And it works. So the syntax is right. And just the assignment of the reduce node is random.

Comment: The assignment of the reduce is random because this is what YARN does - it is a resource scheduler and it assigns resources based on what's available in the cluster when the request for a resource (a reduce slot in your case) is made

Comment: Thank you, Arnon. I have another hadoop streaming question. I use python to do hadoop streaming. We use an AWS hadoop streaming distributed systems which has a master node, and four slave nodes. If I need to install a package on python, I need to install the package on every node of the system to make it work. But in my cases, even I install the python package on every node of the system, the python hadoop streaming job still can not work. I am wondering why. Thank you!

Comment: See the more detailed description of the question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24371816/issues-on-python-packages-on-hadoop-distributed-system-nodes